# PHP _GET after using JS pushstate to change URL

Tags: javascript, php

I am forcing my page to change the url without refreshing the page

```
var pageurl = "mypage.php?myTerm"+newTerm;
                    if(pageurl!=window.location){
                            window.history.pushState({path:pageurl},'',pageurl);
                    }
```

which works great to change the url to newTerm as in mypage.php?myTerm=newTerm

but not if I run

```
    $term = $_GET["myTerm"];
```

I end up with the oldTerm before the url change. The only way the _GET picks up newTerm is if I hit refresh, which puts me at square 1.

Comment: If you are pushing state to the window history object, you are never sending anything back to the server. Sounds to me like you should be making an ajax call back to the server with the new myTerm before pushing a history change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of using `pushState` is to update the URL to reflect the current state of the page as modified by JavaScript.

If you just want to go to a new URL, then assign a value (a string containing the URL) to `location` instead of using `pushState`.

If you want to use `pushState` then change whatever it is in the page that you use `$term` for with JavaScript. Use Ajax to fetch new data from the server if needed.

Comment: yes that worked $('#myTerm').val(newTerm)  but I realized that the reason I did not think it was working was because of links generated in PHP. The links are only created when the page reloads, so they will still be referencing the oldTerm.